# Slow performance WPF animations. Better to use shapes than .png?

Tags: wpf, performance, png

I'm building a prototype app using Expression Blend. It contains a lot of animations (.png's moving into the screen etc.) and they are going kinda slow lately.

Is it better to just draw the items (they must contain gradients!) in Expression Blend than using .png files? (drawed in Photoshop).

I know from Flash that its better using vector's than .png's, so what's the deal with WPF?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As with all performance things it will vary depending on your situation, but based on the experiences I've had, WPF is likely to be quicker at rendering PNG's than vectors, particularly if they are complicated